# Can I use redis cache free edition in production for basic usages?

Tags: caching, redis, redis-cluster

I have a web application where I need to implement caching. I found Redis cache is open source and free to download. But I have also found it's limited for 15 days and after this limit I wont be able to change any configuration.

While I need pretty basic key value pair only, I don't need to change any configuration at all. So, can I put the free version in production or it will raise an issue at later stage?

Comment: Which Redis service you are talking about? If you download  Redis from https://redis.io you have no limitation. If you are looking for a managed service or you can use a free database (30Mb limitation) also on https://redislabs.com/try-free/ - but you have also many other providers)

Comment: I have downloaded from redis.io and I am using it through jedis client in java

Comment: So is this "limited for 15 days " you are talking about?

Comment: I saw in the official website saying after 15 days you wont be able to change any configurations. So I am very confused what they are saying.